# How to handle overflow of unsigned int in C?

Tags: c, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

How can I change line 6 to handle the integer overflow so that this code will never terminate (while still increasing i in each loop iteration)?

```
1 int main() {
2    unsigned int i;
3    i = 1;
4    while (i > 0) {
5        printf("%u \n", i);
6        i *= 2;
7    }
8    printf("%u \n", i);
9 }
```

Comment: You seem to be asking how to allow an integer of limited size to grow indefinitely. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: What actual output do you want?

Comment: `i *= 2;` --> `i *= 2; while (i == 0);`.  Code will not terminate, loop always iterates up.  It just that when `i` becomes 0, an inner forever loop occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Because `i` is unsigned, it is never *less* than zero, but it may at some point be zero.

I might try to guarantee it is always at least `1` with something like this:

```
i = i*2? i*2 : 1;
```

That is: 
If `i*2` is non-zero, then that is the new value of `i`.
Otherwise, `i*2` would be zero, so instead set `i = 1;`